# Create bar plot in ggplot2 - Place data frame values instead of count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to place this data onto a bar plot using ggplot2

[image]

where the column "Clades" would be placed on the X axis and the values from each column (such as the values of 19A, for example) would be place on Y axis

I'm trying something like this:

```
cols = as.vector(names(snv_data)[2:19])
ggplot(df, aes(x=cols)) + geom_bar()
```

But I keep getting this:

[image]

I'm new to ggplot2 so any help is very welcome!

I'm doing this to try and get 7 plots (one for each column such as 19A, 20A, 20B, etc) where each plot would have the Clades on the X-axis and each value from each column as the "counts" on the Y-axis

dput:

```
structure(list(Clades = c("C.T", "A.G", "G.A", "G.C", "T.C", 
"C.A", "G.T", "A.T", "T.A", "T.G", "A.C", "C.G", "A.del", "TAT.del", 
"TCTGGTTTT.del", "TACATG.del", "AGTTCA.del", "GATTTC.del"), `19A` = c(413, 
93, 21, 0, 49, 9, 238, 13, 3, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `20A` = c(7929, 
1920, 1100, 419, 1025, 124, 3730, 124, 22, 45, 64, 17, 8, 19, 
23, 39, 0, 0), `20B` = c(5283, 1447, 2325, 1106, 336, 117, 946, 
137, 35, 53, 123, 11, 9, 10, 21, 1, 0, 0), `20E (EU1)` = c(13086, 
1927, 650, 1337, 1864, 96, 2967, 243, 69, 92, 115, 1486, 27, 
5, 0, 1, 0, 0), `20I (Alpha, V1)` = c(71142, 12966, 12047, 15587, 
14935, 15382, 11270, 12211, 5284, 4273, 430, 99, 5674, 4536, 
4974, 4592, 0, 0), `20J (Gamma, V3)` = c(2822, 654, 883, 409, 
501, 213, 843, 399, 203, 27, 429, 198, 1, 0, 197, 0, 0, 0), `21J (Delta)` = c(166003, 
49195, 26713, 1399, 25824, 15644, 95967, 2011, 329, 11034, 716, 
21087, 10532, 198, 0, 14, 9809, 10503)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("C.T", 
"A.G", "G.A", "G.C", "T.C", "C.A", "G.T", "A.T", "T.A", "T.G", 
"A.C", "C.G", "A.del", "TAT.del", "TCTGGTTTT.del", "TACATG.del", 
"AGTTCA.del", "GATTTC.del"))
```

Comment: I would suggest making this dataset `tidy` using `pivot_longer` and the `tidyverse` library. This way all your different groups (19A,20A etc.) become one column: groups. Then if you want each to be a separate plot you can use `facet_grid(~groups)` which will split each of your groups into their own sub barplot.

Comment: You are getting the top plot because you are not providing any y data to the plot. Also, with `geom_bar` you need to specify `stat = "identity"` if you would like to plot untransformed y values.

Comment: Thank you, @user438383 I added dput()!

Comment: I will give that a try, @AndrewIngalls

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, @cazman! Indeed, after adding your suggestion and using `y=df[,"19A"]` as an example the plot showed up! I was trying something like that before, but I was doing `y="19A"` thinking it would somehow get the values (since I've established the data before the `aes` as `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the previous answer, here is how you can get 7 plots (1 for each Clade, which is how I interpreted the question) using `facet_wrap()`:

```
df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Clades)

ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = Clades,
           y = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Clades),
           stat = 'identity') +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = 'free_y') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the added input, cazman! Both great answers, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

As cazman said in the comments, you need to get your data in long form for it to work with ggplot2 (efficiently).

First, use `pivot_longer()`, and then use ggplot2:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
    pivot_longer(-Clades) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Clades, y=value, fill=name)) + 
    geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Precisely that! Thank you so much for everyone's help! :)